# Django Celery configuration for multiple servers

Tags: django, celery

We have two machines in production ,in both celery is running ? Does it will execute periodic task twice? If yes , then what is the best way to configure it(because there are both asynch and periodic task both)

Answer (score 0):

You execute periodic tasks twice only if you schedule them twice.

This means that you can run multiple workers a the same time but not more than one scheduler process.

For more informations have a look at the docs [here](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)

Comment: hi @tommaso my qusetion was we have CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "rtbd-rejection-mail-runs-every-1-hour-": {
        "task": "rtbdops.tasks.send_rejection_mail_periodic_task",
        "schedule": timedelta(seconds=30),
        "args": (email_host,email_user,recepient)
    },  running in two prod machines will it get execute twice??

Comment: @AvinashGarg its not about settings, its about the amount of scheduler process you execute at the same time (`celery -A proj beat` or `celery -A proj worker -B`)